# Actualizar MariaDB 10.1 a 10.4 en plesk para una sola subscripcion

Tags: mysql, mariadb, magento2, plesk

espero que me puedan ayudar tengo una instalacion de plesk obsidian 18.0.47 y CentOS 7 en mi servidor, tengo varias subcripciones cada una simulando un servidor web para  que cada quien tenga su propio espacio de pruebas, el problema es que uso Magento 2 2.3.5 y estoy buscando actualizar a magento 2.4.5-p1 el cual me exige tener mariadb 10.4 y en la subscripcion tengo mariadb 10.1 es posible actualizar el servidor de bd asociado a esa suscripcion sin perder la data o tener que volcarla para cargarla de nuevo ?. No encuentro como hacerlo ya intente creando una nueva subscripcion con mariadb 10.4 y migrar la data pero se colapsa el innoDB y no pasa la data completa ademas que tarda una eternidad porque son mas de 30gb de informacion.

Comment: La [documentación de Plesk](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213403429-How-to-upgrade-MySQL-5-5-to-5-6-5-7-or-MariaDB-5-5-to-10-0-10-1-10-2-on-Linux-) puede ayudar

Comment: si estaba leyendo ese post pero no me queda claro si hacerlo de esa manera actualiza todas las subscripciones o si se puede hacer sobre una sola

Comment: Dudo que puedas hacerlo, normalmente en los servidores de hosting compartidos todos usan la misma base de datos que haya instalada y si se actualiza, es para todos. En cambio, si que se pueden permitir distintos interpretes de PHP, pero porque no actuan como un servidor, sino como ejecutables bajo demanda.

Comment: Lo que si podrias hacer es montar un VPS mínimo con ese servidor de MariaDB y la versión que quieras instalada y decirle a tus scripts que consulten al servidor MariaDB de ese VPS en lugar del que hay instalado propiamente en tu servidor compartido desde donde se ejecutan los scripts.

Comment: En cuanto a la migración de datos de magento, te recomiendo que entres por PHPMyADMIN y listes todas las tablas para que detectes las que tienen más datos, las cuales seguramente alguna contiene datos irrelevantes que aparentemente no se usan (me viene a la cabeza una tabla denominada `mgn_dataflow_batch_export.ibd` que es una burrada de gorda y que mejor no migres, sino que simplemente copies su estructura... y así con todas las que contengan algun tipo de log inutil e innecesario)